# How to upload Arduino sketches to Atmel chips

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, bootloader, avr, atmel-studio

I am new in this Arduino coding world and I was trying to make a project. I normally used Arduino Unos all the time, but I was facing a problem and that is that the Arduino Uno has only 13 digital pins and 6 analog pins, and some of my friends advise me to use an Arduino Mega, but that costs too much, some to my friends also tell me that I could use only a Atmel chip, which will save money.

But the problem is that I can not burn these chips without a burner. I see online that Arduino Uno has Arduino ISP options also that will allow you to bootload or upload Arduino sketches to those kind of chips, but I have been trying for over 3 months and I cannot figure out how to do that

At present I am working with the ATmega8 chip.

This is my problem:

[image: avrdude error - 1]

Using stk500v1 but the problem is not resolved

[image: avrdude error - 2]

Comment: How many pins do you need? It is actually 19 digital pins and 6 analog pins. The analog pins can be used as digital pins. A typical issue when using an Arduino as an ISP is forgetting to use a resistor or capacitor connected to the reset pins to avoid reset and running the bootloader. The ATmega8 might be an issue as well. Which core are you using for that?

Comment: @MikaelPatel I need 22 digital pins and 7 analog pins, I am using 10 mf capacitor in arduino capacitor VCC side is Arduino RESET and GND side is Arduino GND

Comment: @MikaelPatel: I did not find any core?

Comment: Seems like the atmega8 is an older AVR chip and compatible with the pins on atmega328 https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone. Smaller memory size and the same number of pins (digital/analog).

Comment: @MikaelPatel: Sir at this time I am just testing how it works, When I figure out I will us ATmega 16 ARV Chip

Comment: Try option "-cstk500v1" instead of "-c arduino".

Comment: @MikaelPatel: OK sir

Comment: The problem is not solve
http://www.softbazz.com/jja.jpg

Comment: Time to check the wiring from the Uno to the ATmega8.

Comment: Arduino pin name: reset: 10: , MOSI: 11:, MISO: 12:, SCK: 13:       Atmega Chip pin: 1 (PC6), 17 (PB3), 18 (PB4), 19 (PB5)

Comment: And I also using 10uf capacitor

Comment: Add option "-v" to get more info from the upload.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but a USBasp clone costs little and would likely be delivered long before 3 months had passed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams +1 for saying it before I cracked. Fortunately I was out most of the day.

Comment: Do not really see how that would help :) This is all about helping with hardware debugging (as I see it). Small steps forward to understand where the problems are. Even better would be to just sent the HEX file off to a company that did all the work for you. But where is the fun in that.

Comment: It wouldn't solve the problem, but it would get the job done. Which is why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: You say the problem "needs 22 digital pins and 7 analog pins" which is 29 pins. ATmega8/16/328 come in 28 and 32 pin packages. Several pins are used for ground and power, and the reset pin should be left free too. So it is not possible to have 29 pins. So what is your plan to create 29 I/O pins? The options are: a) use multiple ATmega chips, b) use some sort of I/O extender (e.g. shift register, multiplexer, etc), or c) use a different chip?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do in this situation is to crank up the verbosity level on the invocation of `avrdude`. You do this by adding one or more `-v` flags to the command line. With `-v -v -v -v`, you get maximum verbosity.

From your two logs, it appears that the initial handshake with the microcontroller was successful (which would indicate that your connections were good), but then the signature reading turns out quite badly. This is a rather unusual combination which makes me wonder whether you may have misidentified what microcontroller you have.

Comment: I was just trying in our way, and this is the result,

Comment: http://www.softbazz.com/main.html

Comment: That confirms that the initial handshake was good, so your connections must be OK, but that somehow a nonsense signature was read. This is puzzling. Unfortunately, the ATmega8 is quite old, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong here.